# pythonw missing with Enthought's distribution of Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, enthought

I have a wxPython GUI that needs to run with Python 3 using both Enthought Python (EDM) and Anaconda Python.

The problem is, when using Anaconda Python I have to use pythonw or the script fails with this error:

```
This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in on the main display of your Mac.
```

Previously, using Python 2.x, I solved this by specifying:

```
#/usr/bin/env pythonw
```

which worked for both Canopy Python 2 and Anaconda Python 2.

However, EDM Python 3 seems to lack pythonw.exe, so the I have to edit the shebang line to

```
#/usr/bin/env python
```

to get my script to run in with EDM python 3.

So, is there a way to use the pythonw executable with EDM python 3?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just create a script called `pythonw` and put it in `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/bin/env python "$@"
```